# Trouble calling other class in toString method Java

Tags: java, class, object, tostring

I feel stupid about this but I'm having trouble with the very last part of the book class. I can't seem to figure out what to put in the last segment of the two string. It's supposed to take input of a book name, publisher name, and review of a book. If no review it should print 0.00(0) but i keep getting back null. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Book Class**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Book {

private String title;
private String publisher;
private Review bookReview;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

public Book(String title, String publisher, Review bookRev) {

    this.title = title;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    bookReview = bookRev;
}

public Book() {

    title = "?";
    publisher = "?";
    Review rev = new Review();
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}
public Review getReview() {
    return bookReview;
}
public void setTitle(String aTitle) {
    title = aTitle;
}
public void setPublisher(String aPublisher) {
    publisher = aPublisher;
}
public void addRating(double rate) {
    Review rev = new Review();
    rev.updateRating(rate);
}
public String toString() {
    return "\n" + "Title:" + "\t" + title + "," + "\n" + 
            "Publisher:" + "\t" + publisher + "," + "\n" +
            "Reviews:" + "\t" + bookReview + "\n\n";
}
}
```

**Review Class**

```
public class Review {

private int numberOfReviews;
private double sumOfRatings;
private double average;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

public Review(int numRev, double sumRat, double average) {

    numberOfReviews = numRev;
    sumOfRatings = sumRat;
    this.average = average;
}

public Review() {

    numberOfReviews = 0;
    sumOfRatings = 0.0;
    average = 0.0;
}

public void updateRating(double rating) {

    numberOfReviews ++;
    sumOfRatings = sumOfRatings + rating;
    if (numberOfReviews > 0) {
        average = sumOfRatings / numberOfReviews;
    }
}

public String toString() {

    return "Reviews:" + "\t" + format.format(average) + "(" + numberOfReviews + ")";
}
}

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Assignment4
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
   // local variables, can be accessed anywhere from the main method
   char input1 = 'Z';
   String inputInfo;
   String bookTitle;
   String bookPublisher;
   double rating;
   String line = new String();

   // instantiate a Book object
   Book book1 = new Book();

   printMenu();

   //Create a Scanner object to read user input
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


   do  // will ask for user input
    {
     System.out.println("What action would you like to perform?");
     line = scan.nextLine();

     if (line.length() == 1)
      {
       input1 = line.charAt(0);
       input1 = Character.toUpperCase(input1);

       // matches one of the case statement
       switch (input1)
        {
         case 'A':   //Add Book
           book1 = new Book();
           System.out.print("Please enter the book information:\n");
           System.out.print("Enter a book title:\n");
           bookTitle = scan.nextLine();
           book1.setTitle(bookTitle);

           System.out.print("Enter its publisher:\n");
           bookPublisher = scan.nextLine();
           book1.setPublisher(bookPublisher);
           break;
         case 'D':   //Display Book
           System.out.print(book1);
           break;
         case 'Q':   //Quit
           break;
         case 'R':   //Add Rating
           System.out.print("Please give a rating of the book:\n");
           rating = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
           book1.addRating(rating);
           break;
         case '?':   //Display Menu
           printMenu();
           break;
         default:
           System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
           break;
        }
      }
     else
      {
       System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
      }
    } while (input1 != 'Q' || line.length() != 1);
  }


 /** The method printMenu displays the menu to a user**/
public static void printMenu()
{
 System.out.print("Choice\t\tAction\n" +
                    "------\t\t------\n" +
                    "A\t\tAdd Book\n" +
                    "D\t\tDisplay Book\n" +
                    "Q\t\tQuit\n" +
                    "R\t\tGive Rating\n" +
                    "?\t\tDisplay Help\n\n");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that instantiates the Book object?

Comment: are you getting "Reviews:null" as output

Comment: Can you please specify code from which you are calling these objects?

Comment: @Vihar yes I keep getting null in the reviews output whether i add a review or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the culprit

```
public void addRating(double rate) {
    Review rev = new Review();
    rev.updateRating(rate);
}
```

what you are doing is creating a new object,which dies after method call
whenever you are adding a rating add it to your instance variable rather than local variable, i.e. something like this

```
 public void addRating(double rate) {
        bookReview = new Review();
        bookReview.updateRating(rate);
    }
```

due to this your `reviewBook` will get updated and will print required ,result

<---new Edit--->

view your Book class default constructor

you are making a new object by using `Review rev = new Review();` but it should really be `bookReview = new Review();` you are making a new object, but in `toString` only bookReview will be accessible so you need to initialize that.

Comment: I changed it as you suggested but it is still coming back as null unfortunately

Comment: finally found your real culprit, updating my answer :)

Comment: That fixed that problem but now I am seeing that the average rating is not being computed and the number of reviews is not being incremented. Instead the old review is just replaced by the new one and the number of reviews stays at 1. I believe the problem lies in the updateRating method but I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong

Comment: Yes you need to update that, try for a while if you don't get that,  ping back here

Comment: does your addRating() contain this line? `bookReview = new Review();` if yes remove it, everything looks fine

Comment: Yup that did it, thanks a lot, I think I understand it a lot better now!

Comment: Hahaha no issues...try reading. ' head first java'  if you want to learn Java

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your "Review" object.

I am just using some sample data to initialize both Book And Review :

```
Review reviewObj = new Review(23, 5, 133);
Mainclass obj  = new Mainclass("first things first", "s.covey", reviewObj);
```

And below is the output:

```
Title:  first things first,
Publisher:  s.covey,
Reviews:    Reviews:    133.00(23)
```